# How do I target a member which's name is equal to a variable string without using eval()?

Tags: javascript

```js
q1 = {
  qTxt: "I want this text to be displayed in the alert box.",
  usedBefore: true
};

var foo = "q1"
alert(eval(foo).qTxt);
```

While searching other answers on StackOverflow, I found a solution to my problem which uses *eval()*.
But I did read before that *eval()* is bad (eval is evil) and it shouldn't be used.

If it really is a bad to use it, how could I get the same result.

I heard of something like *alert(member['foo'])*, but when I tried to use it, it didn't work: *alert(['foo']qTxt);*

**EDIT:** I didn't get an answer for my problem from the "duplicate". That question only shows how to change the parameter, but I'm trying to change the first part (q1) which seems to be not working for me.

**EDIT 2:** My code.

```js
q1 = {
  qTxt: "The answer is true.",
  usedBefore: false
};
    
    var foo = "q1";
    alert([foo].qTxt); // without the dot, an error  comes up
```

Comment: Hmm [this is probably a better duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Check it over again, I didn't find an answer from what you put as the "duplicate". I actually did look at those questions before I asked this one.

Comment: You can't access variables with that notation. What you need to do is put `q1` in an object, let's call it `questions`, have a property named `q1` in there, and use `questions[questionName]` to look up the question, assuming `questionName` holds the string "q1".

Comment: If you simply have `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, etc., in there, why bother? Just use an array.

Comment: @doug65536 - if I'm going to use arrays, how would I target the array names instead, then?

Comment: If you named the array `questions`, then you would use the `length` property of the array. Each entry is numbered from `0` to `questions.length-1`. You use the same notation, put the array index (the 0-based number) in square brackets: `questions[i]`. Another option, if you want to process all of the questions at once, is to use `questions.forEach(function(question) { /* use question.qTxt etc */ });`